# Does Spring offer a way to load different application.properties file for each test method?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, testing, application.properties

So, for each @Test, I would like to load a different application.properties file.
One of the workarounds is to create a class for each of the tests, but I think it is too much.
All I need in each @Test, is only one property in application.properties file to be different. So if there is a way to explicitly assign value to that one property in each test, that would also do the work.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ProtocolBeansTest
{

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    public void test1()
    {
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class,
                            () -> applicationContext.getBean(KafkaTopicConfig.class));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class, () -> applicationContext.getBean(Producer.class));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class, () -> applicationContext.getBean(Consumer.class));
        Assert.assertNotNull(applicationContext.getBean(TcpConfig.class));
        Assert.assertNotNull(applicationContext.getBean(MyController.class));
        Assert.assertNotNull(applicationContext.getBean(ScheduledTasks.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void testKafkaBeansAreOnOthersAreOff()
    {
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class, () -> applicationContext.getBean(TcpConfig.class));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class,
                            () -> applicationContext.getBean(KokosProtoController.class));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class,
                            () -> applicationContext.getBean(ScheduledTasks.class));
        Assert.assertNotNull(applicationContext.getBean(KafkaTopicConfig.class));
        Assert.assertNotNull(applicationContext.getBean(Producer.class));
        Assert.assertNotNull(applicationContext.getBean(Consumer.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void test3()
    {
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class, () -> applicationContext.getBean(TcpConfig.class));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class,
                            () -> applicationContext.getBean(KokosProtoController.class));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class,
                            () -> applicationContext.getBean(ScheduledTasks.class));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class,
                            () -> applicationContext.getBean(KafkaTopicConfig.class));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class, () -> applicationContext.getBean(Producer.class));
        Assert.assertThrows(NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.class, () -> applicationContext.getBean(Consumer.class));
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = PROTOCOL_DATA_TYPE,
                           havingValue = KAFKA_PROTOCOL_TYPE)
    public static class SomeServiceMockConfig
    {

        @MockBean
        private static KafkaTopicConfig kafkaTopicConfig;

    }

}
```

Comment: You are testing way too many things at the same time. You definitely should split your tests...

Comment: @GuillaumeF.
Hi and thanks for fast response! So you mean to split these tests into different test classes?